# How can I determine the index of the same set of characters between two strings that are of different lengths?

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, string

I apologize up front for the title, I'm not sure how to word the question.

I am trying to find the index for a similar character or set of characters in two different, but similar strings.

- String A: `I <color=red><b>really</b></color> don't like spiders!`
- String B: `I really don't like spiders!`

The relevant text is the same, however `A` has some formatting while `B` does not. I got `B` by taking `A` and running a regex to find and replace all `<contents>` with an empty string.

Now lets say I have selected a character at an index of 9 in `B`, this would be the letter `d` in the word `don't`. How can I then determine in string `A` that the letter `d` in `don't` needs to also be selected which is at an index of 35 (if I counted correctly)?

Edit: Possibly important information, these tags are for the rich text within Unity. Very similar to HTML in almost all regards.

Comment: You should check out the HtmlAgilityPack, you shouldn't be using regexes with html

Comment: I would suggest that you read the entire word and then select the character in it. Otherwise, there is no symmetry in the both strings. You can select the word and then the character.

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: You absolutely need to *parse* that. And once you do that, it’s not too difficult to differ between text and formatting instructions (which you parsed and as such are meta information).

Comment: This is actually an odd form of BBCode in Unity that's similar to HTML, though not compatible. I initially only wanted to strip the formatting which was hilariously easy with a regular expression. Though now I realized that I need to find the index of both when copying to clipboard if I want to copy formatted text. It's a lengthy explanation as to "why" I need it, mostly workarounds for Unity's very limited UI system.

Comment: @poke Can you expand on that? What meta information would I be able to keep that will enable me to match character (or set of characters) in the two strings up?

Comment: It depends on how complex you make it; you could get a whole syntax tree that has the text as nodes and contains the formatting information as meta data. Or you have just a flat list like `[('I ', None), ('really', ['color:red', 'bold']), (' don\'t like spiders!', None)]`; where the second element contains the formatting information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already suggested in the comments, you should write your own parser for this format that keeps the formatting as metadata next to the text. For example, you could keep a simple list of string parts where each part represents consecutive text with the same formatting.

You could start with something simplistic as this:

```
import re

def parse (string):
    it = iter([None] + re.split('(<[^>]+>)', string))

    parsed = []
    curFormat = {}
    for fmt, text in zip(it, it):
        if fmt is None:
            curFormat = {}
        elif fmt.startswith('</'):
            fmt = fmt[2:-1]
            del curFormat[fmt]
        else:
            fmt = fmt[1:-1]
            if '=' in fmt:
                name, value = fmt.split('=', 1)
                curFormat[name] = value
            else:
                curFormat[fmt] = True

        if text != '':
            parsed.append((text, list(curFormat.items())))

    return parsed
```

For your text, this will give you the following result:

```
>>> text = "I <color=red><b>really</b></color> don't like spiders!"
>>> parsed = parse(text)
>>> parsed
[('I ', []), ('really', [('color', 'red'), ('b', True)]), (" don't like spiders!", [])]
```

As you can see, you get pairs of text, with a list of formatting information for that particular part of text. If you then want to get the underlying text, you can just iterate the first list elements:

```
>>> ''.join(t for t, fmt in parsed)
"I really don't like spiders!"
```

And on top of that, you can also create your own indexing method (note that this one is *really crude*):

```
def index (parsed, start, length):
    output = ''
    for t, fmt in parsed:
        if start < 0:
            output += t
        elif start > len(t):
            start -= len(t)
        else:
            output += t[start:]
            start = -1
        if len(output) > length:
            return output[:length]
    return output
```

```
>>> index(parsed, 4, 5)
'ally '
>>> index(parsed, 7, 6)
"y don'"
```

Finally, you can put this all inside a custom type, which implements the iterator protocol and the senquence protocol, so you can use it like a normal string.

Comment: Thanks for this. I took your suggestion and made a solution under the same concept.